# I'm trying to connect with smtp email when I got this error, how can I fixed this?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to connect with smtp email when I got this error, how can I fixed this? It says "
Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\phpmailer\index.php on line 9

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\phpmailer\index.php on line 9"

here is my code

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp-relay.sendinblue.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'Renz');
    //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
   
    //Attachments
   

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
};
```

Comment: Did you use composer to install PHPMailer?

Comment: Well, does `vendor/autoload.php` exist? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes I use composer and the vendor/autoload.php exists

Comment: To be precise, does `C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll\phpmailer\vendor\autoload.php` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `autoload.php` exists, it will be a path problem. The current working directory might not be where you think it is, so perhaps try changing it to:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

which will force it to be relative to this file.

@Markus AO's comment made me think of something else. Your path looks a bit odd. When you use PHPMailer from a project, you would normally expect PHPMailer to be *inside* the project, but it looks like you've done the reverse, putting your scripts inside PHPMailer's folder. I'd expect your project to look something like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\payroll
    index.php
    \vendor
        autoload.php
        \composer
        \PHPMailer
            \src
                PHPMailer.php
                ...
```

but it looks like you've arranged it inside out.

Comment: Also typically `vendor/autoload.php` would appear _before_ `use PHPMailer` unless I'm terribly confused (which is always possible).

Comment: No, convention puts use statements first. They are just local aliases and don’t have anything to do with loading files.

Comment: Oh yes, right you are. Any non-existing whatever will pass in a use alias statement. I always imagined they would trigger an error, as would happen inside a class when using `use` for traits.

Comment: `use` statements don't have to make sense – they only matter if they actually match something that exists when it comes to instantiation. Try adding `use banana/otter` and you'll see it will be harmless and do nothing unless you happen to call `new otter()` later. They *only* apply to the file they appear in.

Comment: In fact I did use some foo\bars following your comment to satisfy my curiosity. At times I've hoped that it were possible to optionally apply use statements globally to eliminate some boilerplate that happens in every other file using staple utility classes, but it seems not to be possible. Suppose there's a reason for that.

Comment: Use statements are just to make working with namespaces less verbose, so you don't have to use FQCNs everywhere, to disambiguate class name clashes, and you only need them for classes you're actually using. Modern IDEs take care of them for you (adding them automatically, removing ones you're not using), so I don't think about them much any more!